# create PCAP file for captured packet in c

Tags: c, linux, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

I am working on a tool though which I am able to capture incoming packets (l2 buffer and L2 length, payload) in an interface and I am able to print that packet on console.
Now I want to write these packets to a `pcap` file so that I can transfer this file to other platform and read packet info.

How I can open a pcap file and write packet buffer to pcap file?
How can I fill `struct pcap_file_header`?

Answer (score 2):

use `pcap_dump` to save the packet... this code might be useful :)

http://file-hub.com/cmd:thread/140400

Comment: I have packet buffer which I want to write to a pcap file

Comment: how are you reading the packets? If you use `pcap_loop` with a dispatch function the packet header and packet data will be passed to that function... do you want to share your code? you might get an answer that better suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

For  writing pcap use library 
[pcap_file_generator](https://github.com/wkoroy/pcap_file_generator)

Using:

```
int i=0;
  const int  PKTS_COUNT = 212000;
  int PKTS_LEN =  540;
  static ethernet_data_t  eda;
  eda.len = PKTS_LEN;

  PCAPFILE * pfl = lpcap_create("./pcaplibtestfile.pcap");
  for( i=0;i< PKTS_COUNT;i++ )
  {
    /* TODO:  fill data   memcpy(eda.data , YOUR_DATA_BUF,SIZE_YOUR_DATA_BUF  );
       eda.len = SIZE_YOUR_DATA_BUF;
    */
   lpcap_write_data( pfl , &eda , i, 0 );
  }
  lpcap_close_file( pfl );
```